# Derivation of 42-Letter Name of G-d

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, shemos-sacred-names

I understand that from the first 42 letters of Breishis, it is possible to derive the 42-letter name of G-d that is indicated within the Ana Bekoach prayer.  Where could find out more about the mathematical formula used to go from the first 42 letters of Breishis to the actual 42-letter name known to us through Ana Bekoach?

Answer (score 2):

[Ramak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Jacob_Cordovero) in [Pardes Rimonim 12:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pardes_Rimonim.21.13?lang=he) gives a derivation of the 42-letter Name from the first 42 letters of the Torah, using various letter substitution systems.

To give a flavor, here are the derivations of the first few letters (parentheses indicate the substitution system employed):

- ב=א (אבג"ד)
- ר=ט (אלב"ם) =ב (אח"ס בט"ע)
- א=י (אי"ק) =ג (אח"ס בט"ע)
- ש=י (אלב"ם)
- י=א (אי"ק) =ת (א"ת ב"ש)
- ת=כ (אלב"ם) =צ (אח"ס בט"ע)

Comment: Is _derive_ the right word? I'd imagine _reveal_ is better but I am genuinely asking.

Comment: I was just using the word as used in the OP. Either way, Ramak talks about אופן מוצאו מהפסוקים, which to me has more of a sense of derivation as opposed to revelation.